# What is the Smalltalk equivalent of Java's static?

Tags: java, oop, programming-languages, smalltalk

What is the Smalltalk equivalent of Java's static fields and methods? IOW, what do the Smalltalkers do when they need class level data and/or methods?

Comment: Not worthy of a "formal" answer, but I stumbled across this page that might help you: http://per.bothner.com/papers/smalltalk.html .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We use class-side methods/instance variables. A class is an object, after all, so can have methods.

For instance, the Rectangle class has a method #origin:corner: so you may write

```
Rectangle origin: 0@0 corner: 100@100
```

to create a Rectangle. This is just the message #origin:corner: sent to the object called Rectangle (a class is an object!) with the two Points as parameters.

Class-side instance variables work much the same way. A class, being an object, may have instance variables. From the SUnit library:

```
TestCase class
  instanceVariableNames: 'history'
```

and then TestCase class exposes this in the usual way, with a getter/setter (#history and #history:).

EDIT: The `@` I used has caused a fair bit of discussion. It's what's called a [binary message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Messages), which allows one to define selectors that look just what other languages would call infix operators. For instance, `3 + 4`, or `0@0`. In the case of `@`, the `Number` class defines a method called `@` taking a parameter `y`, defined as `^Point x: self y: y` - "return a Point whose x coordinate is my own value and whose y coordinate is the parameter".

Point is an ordered pair, but of course there's nothing stopping one from defining higher-dimensional versions. `Point` might define a method called `@` that looked like this, for instance: `^Triple x: self x y: self y z: z` - "return a point in R^3 whose x, y coordinates are my own, and whose z coordinate is the given parameter".

Comment: Do any languages other than Smalltalk use @ to delimit the different coordinates of a point? I don't believe I've seen that specific syntax before.

Comment: Does that `@` indicate a tuple?

Comment: @ is a "binary message" - a message that takes a single parameter, but doesn't need the usual trailing :. Number defines a method called @ that returns a Point: ^Point x: self y: y (where y is the sole parameter, obviously).

Answer (score 4):

The most important mind-shift needed if you come to Smalltalk from Java or such, is that classes are objects.

A static in Java-like languages can have many different semantics. Usually this has to do with visibility. You need an object that is independent from any instances of a class, but you want to restrict the visibility of this object to within the class, that is: only visible from instances of the class or the class itself (in Smalltalk, because in Java classes are not first-class objects).

In Smalltalk you usually have more options for this:

1. Class instance variables
2. Class variables or pool variables (depending on your Smalltalk dialect)

A class instance variable is indeed just like an instance variable of instances of any class: the class has this property, and this can be made accessible for any instance of the class by providing a getter method on the class (not on the instances, we call this a class method). This is useful if you have default values and such. Example:

Define a class `Car`, with instance variable `colour`, PLUS a class instance variable `defaultColour` (which of course would have the value "BLACK" ;-))

```
Smalltalk defineClass: #Car
    superclass: #{Core.Object}
    indexedType: #none
    private: false
    instanceVariableNames: 'colour '
    classInstanceVariableNames: 'defaultColour'
    imports: ''
    category: ''
```

This is a class definition (actually a message to the object `Smalltalk`) in VisualWorks Smalltalk.
If you create a subclass of `Car`, it inherits the class instance variable `defaultColour`, as a normal object would do as well. If the `defaultColour` class instance variable has a value, the subclass also inherits this value!

Answer (score 2):

In most types of Smalltalk you have class variables. Typically class variables are used for e.g. [singletons](http://www.silversoft.net/docs/dp/hires/pat3efso.htm). There are differences in the types of variables that you can use between flavors of Smalltalk though, so read the documentation on this point for your particular implementation.