# Smalltalk exotic features

Tags: smalltalk

Smalltalk syntax (and features) can be found pretty exotic (and even disturbing) when you come from a more C-like syntax world. I found myself losing time with some
I would be interested in learning knowing what you found really exotic compared to more classic/mainstream languages and that you think helps to understand the language.

For example, evaluation with logic operators :

- `(object1 = object2) & (object3 = object4)` : this will evaluate the whole expression, even if the left part is false, the rest will be evaluated.
- `(object1 = object2) and: [object3 = object4]` : this will evaluate the left part, and only will evaluate the right part if the first is true.

Comment: How is any of this exotic? Think in terms of sending messages. You're in a room full of people, so am I; I want to ask you a question, so I open my mouth and start saying words. You receive these words, and react accordingly. Either by ignoring them, responding to them or performing some bodily expression to communicate a response. It's actually more foundational than exotic when you stop and think about it how it's intended.

Comment: As I said, when I say "exotic", it means "exotic compared to classic/mainstream C/Java-like language". I agree that message sending makes SmallTalk closer to human thinking than other languages, but we (programmers, or at least me) are formatted to think in a C world. That was just my point.

Comment: Coming from a Delphi background, I'm used to boolean expressions that might or might not be evaluated in either fashion, based on a compiler switch!

Comment: about & and `and`, they seems not exotic, but logical to me; and I have a C/asm background

Comment: I agree with `&`: it behaves exactly the same as it does in C/Java. The "exotic" thing here is that you send the `and:` message (with a code block as an argument) to the result of the comparison.

Comment: @joachim: but an `&&` operator that behaves the same as in C/Java would require a specific rule to evaluate its right operand lazily. Using a keyword message with a block argument makes it possible to define the lazy semantics while keeping Smalltalk semantics uniform and minimalistic.

Answer (score 10):

Everything is an object, and everything above the VM's available for inspection and modification. (Primitives are part of the VM, conceptually at least.) Even your call stack's available (`thisContext`) - Seaside implemented continuations back in the day by simply swizzling down the call stack into a stream, and restoring it (returning to the continuation) by simply reading out activation frames from that stream!

You can construct a selector from a string and turn it into a `Symbol` and send it as a message: `self perform: 'this', 'That'` will do the same thing as `self thisThat`. (But don't do this, for the same reasons you should avoid `eval` in both Lisps and PHP: very hard to debug!)

Message passing: it's [not method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102695/what-are-the-key-differences-between-oo-in-smalltalk-and-java/3104741#3104741)!

[`#become:`](http://gbracha.blogspot.com/2009/07/miracle-of-become.html) is probably a bit of a shock to anyone who hasn't seen it before. (tl;dr a wholesale swapping of two object pointers - all references to B now point to A, and all references to A now point to B)

Answer (score 4):

Primitves

```
someMethod
  <primitive 14122 wtf>
  "fail and execute the following"
  [self] inlineCopyInject: [:t1 | self].
```

Answer (score 4):

My first wrestling session with Smalltalk was the metaclass implementation.

Consider this:

What is the class of `'This is a string'`? Well, something like `String`.

What is the class of `String`? `String class`. Note: this is a class, but it has no name, it just prints itself as 'String class'.

What is the class of `String class`? `Metaclass`. Note: this is a named class.

What is the class of `Metaclass`? As you might expect (or not) this is `Metaclass class`. Of which, again as you might expect, the class is `Metaclass` again.

This is the first circularity. Another one which I found rather esoteric at first (of course, now I eat metaclasses for breakfast) is the next one:

What is the superclass of `String`? `Object` (eventually, different implementations of Smalltalk have different class hierarchies of these basic classes).

What is the superclass of `Object`? `nil`. Now this is an interesting answer in Smalltalk, because it actually is an object! `nil class` answers `UndefinedObject`. Of which the superclass is ... `Object`.

Navigating through the superclass and instance of relations was a real rollercoster ride for me in those days...

Comment: In Squeak, `Object` subclasses `ProtoObject`, which subclasses `nil`. `nil` is an `UndefinedObject`, subclassing `Object`. Your point still stands though :)

Answer (score 4):

How about selective breakpointing (which I actually use at times):

```
foo
    thisContext sender selector == #bar ifTrue:[ self halt ].
    ...
```

will debug itself, but only if called from bar. Useful, if foo is called for from zillion other places and a regular breakpoint hits too often.

Answer (score 3):

I've always been fond of the Smalltalk quine:

```
quine
     ^thisContext method getSource
```

(Pharo version.)